# How to put strong tags around expressions inside curly braces?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<DialogTitle>
  <p>
    Are you sure you want to delete{" "}{project ? project.title : "this project"}?    
  </p>     
</DialogTitle>
```

I've been trying this solution, but no results:

```
`<strong>` `{project? project.title: "this project"}` `</strong>` but it didn't work.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. I hope it will helps you.

```
<DialogTitle>
  <p>
     Are you sure you want to delete{" "}{project ? <strong> 
     {project.title}</strong> : "this project"}
   </p> 
</DialogTitle>
```

Demo Link:https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-akxxud

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<DialogTitle>
  <p>
    {"Are you sure you want to delete "}<strong>{project ? project.title : "this project"}</strong>
  </p>
<DialogTitle>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample Demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/strong-in-dialog-title-11slh) for your ref.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<DialogTitle>
 <p>
    Are you sure you want to delete <strong>{project ? project.title : "this project ?"}</strong>
  </p>
<DialogTitle>
```